# Create a map of string to List

Tags: go

I'd like to create a map of string to `container/list.List` instances. Is this the correct way to go about it?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "container/list"
)

func main() {
    x := make(map[string]*list.List)

    x["key"] = list.New()
    x["key"].PushBack("value")

    fmt.Println(x["key"].Front().Value)
}
```

Comment: sure, but I can't help but wonder why you would need such a thing unless you were doing some really ambiguous processing

Comment: Congratulations, your code simply [works](http://play.golang.org/p/EuYA92BtOR).

Comment: Sure, but is it the *right* way of doing this?

Comment: Depends on the task, but there's nothing strange with the code. Use of a linked list is prety common, mapping a key to some value as well - and there's nothing wrong if the value is a container (or whatever does the job).

Comment: just barely. http://play.golang.org/p/8ov4yUKGpp

Comment: Once more: please, don't use container/List, use slices. 99% of the time you are better off learning how to use slices properly: http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks and the remaining 1% you should probably use container/Ring.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Whenever I've wanted to use a `List` I've found that a slice was the right choice, eg

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := make(map[string][]string)

    x["key"] = append(x["key"], "value")
    x["key"] = append(x["key"], "value1")

    fmt.Println(x["key"][0])
    fmt.Println(x["key"][1])
}
```

Comment: But, the slice is kind of array, so it is not practical when the data structure needs frequent insertion/delete operations on the elements.

Comment: @yongrae, frequent inserts *at the end* of slice is fine, but got your point.

Answer (score 46):

My favorite syntax for declaring a map of string to slice of string:

```
mapOfSlices := map[string][]string{
    "first": {},
    "second": []string{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"},
    "third": []string{"quarter", "half"},
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how could I have `first` value as another map instead of an empty array? What would be the syntax?

Comment: You can omit the redundant `[]string` type. So the third key for e.g. could be `"third": {"quarter", "half"},`

Comment: Regarding, **You can omit the redundant []string type...**, yes, for example, the following will give a warning: `map[string][]string{"Content-Length": []string{"1"}}`. It should be: `map[string][]string{"Content-Length": {"1"}}`.

Answer (score 8):

there's nothing technically incorrect about what you've written, but you should define your own type around `map[string]*list.List` to avoid some pitfalls, like trying to call the `.Front()` method on a nil pointer.  Or make it a `map[string]list.List` to avoid that situation.  A list.List is just a pair of pointers and a length value; using a list.List pointer in your map just adds the extra case of a nil pointer on top of the case of an empty list.  In either situation,  you should define a new struct for this use case.

I would be inclined to write it like this:
http://play.golang.org/p/yCTYdGVa5G

Comment: Thanks for code link, I realise this question is _really_ old, just wondering why in your `Add` method you checked if the slice is ok? I thought you could append to a nil slice and it will resize for you, e.g. this should work even if `s[key]` is a nil slice:  `append(s[key], value)`

Comment: I don't remember, it was so long ago. Not sure if that was supported back then. Maybe I liked that it lets you explicitly set the initial size of the inner slices? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯