# In Go how can I iterate over a pointer list?

Tags: go

I want to iterate over this :

```
*list.List
```

How can I do it?

```
func Foo(key string, values *list.List) string {
...

//I want to iterate and get value from "values"
}
```

this Foo is being called like this:

```
kvs := make(map[string]*list.List)
res := Foo(k, kvs[k]) //k is string
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason for using a list and not just a slice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the example @ http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/ :

```
func Foo(key string, vl *list.List) string {
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        v := e.Value
    }
    return ""
}
```

*//edit* : check [Create a Golang map of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677934/create-a-golang-map-of-lists?rq=1)