# go - creating dictionary with values as list

Tags: go

I want to create dict in go language, but its value contains lists

```
dict= {
"A" : ["1", "2"],
"B" : ["3", "4"]
}
```

How can we create the same in go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677934/create-a-golang-map-of-lists

Answer (score 6):

You can create a map of string to slice of strings:

```
func main() {

    m := make(map[string][]string)

    // Each string in the m maps to a string slice
    m["A"] = []string{"1", "2"}
    m["B"] = []string{"3", "4"}
    fmt.Println(m["A"])

    // Adding to the list of a particular key
    m["A"] = append(m["A"], "10")

    // Creating a new key can be done similarly
    m["C"] = append(m["C"], "100")

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)

    fmt.Printf("m[\"C\"] = %#v\n", m["C"]) // m["C"] = []string{"100"}
}
```