# How can I create a map of two lists where one list is again a map?

Tags: go

I want to create a structure like below

```
{
  "acc_id" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "acc_info" : [
          {
           "name": "abc"
          },
          {
           "name": "pqr"
          }
  ]
}
```

I have one list which should populate `acc_id` and one set which should populate `acc_info`.

I am very new to go, but trying to create a static variable for this structure but struggling.

tried to create something like this but I know it's not correct.

```
result := make(map[string][]map[string]string)
```

can anyone help me on this?

I find this question but not helpful : [Create a Golang map of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677934/create-a-golang-map-of-lists)

Comment: In Go (or any statically typed language), your first instinct should not be to use maps. This data looks very well defined and should be expressed with struct types. For Go there is [this tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) which can generate such types from JSON documents. Don't dismiss the safety of static type checks so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Refer golang blog [post](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) for more information.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type accountInfo struct {
    AccID   []int               `json:"acc_id"`
    AccInfo []map[string]string `json:"acc_info"`
}

func main() {
    t := accountInfo{
        AccID: []int{1, 2, 3, 4},
        AccInfo: []map[string]string{
            map[string]string{"name": "abc"},
            map[string]string{"name": "pqr"},
        },
    }
    res, err := json.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, what if I want to populate values on iterating... I have `acc_ids := make([]gocql.UUID, 0, 100)` which should populate as acc_ids and a set `var broadcasters = set.New(set.ThreadSafe)` should populate for `account_info`